# module 'tensorflow.keras.applications' has no attribute 'convnext'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kaggle, transfer-learning

I'm trying to use ConvNextXLarge and I have this code:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.convnext.ConvNeXtXLarge(
  model_name='convnext_xlarge',
  include_top=True,
  include_preprocessing=True,
  weights='imagenet',
  input_tensor=None,
  input_shape=None,
  pooling=None,
  classes=1000,
  classifier_activation='softmax'
)
```

But I get the error in the title:

> module 'tensorflow.keras.applications' has no attribute 'convnext'

I'm pretty sure it is related to the fact that in Kaggle I use tensorflow v2.6 but I don't know how to upgrade

Comment: For starters, try to reinstall `tensorflow`. Use `pip uninstall tensorflow` and `pip install tensorflow`. In your code, there is a spelling issue, it isn't `ConvNeXtXLarge`, but `ConvNextLarge`. Your use should be like this: `tf.keras.applications.convnext.ConvNeXtLarge`

Comment: If even that doesn't work, then try to directly obtain it using `from tensorflow.keras.applications import ConvNeXtLarge` and then use it.

Comment: conv-next may be available to tf 2.10, recheck.

Comment: Please try again importing the `tf.keras.applications.convnext.ConvNeXtXLarge` api with Tensorflow 2.10 or 2.11. You can upgrade the tensorflow using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` or by providing a specific version `pip install tensorflow==2.10`.

Answer (score 1):

Attribution convnext come to TensorFlow in v2.11, as you said update is necessary. If using pip simple,

> > pip install tensorflow --upgrade

, is fine if you don't have lot of dependencies.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).